# Are there any gliders that can fly over the Himalayas?

Tags: glider, high-altitude, sailplane, mountain-flying

Do gliders (sailplanes) use ridge and wave lift in the Himalayas to go to extreme altitudes, possibly above Everest's peak?

Comment: Here is a link answering my question, provided by user _mins_ but the comment has been deleted in the meantime. https://www.adventurealternative.com/destinations/nepal/himalayan-glider-flight/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Do gliders (sailplanes) use ridge and wave lift in the Himalayas to go to extreme altitudes, possibly above Everest's peak?*

Yes, there are gliders touring Himalayan peaks over 8,000m, including Annapurna and Everest, using mountain waves. [Montain waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_wave) differ from [ridge waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_lift) as they are created on the leeward side of the mountain. They can be flown without being close to the relief.

**Gliders over Himalayas**

Example with this [Stemme S10VT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemme_S10) motorglider:

[image]

The image is extracted from an advertising page of the [company doing this business](https://www.adventurealternative.com/destinations/nepal/himalayan-glider-flight/). The glider has a service ceiling of 9,140m. Flight is done with oxygen masks in a non pressurized cockpit.

Video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATnNWnlLuT8). From the video:

[image]

**Mountain waves**

These flights are linked to the [Mountain-Wave-Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Wave_Project), initiated by [René Heise](https://www.gmaccc.org/individual-members/rene-heise) and [Klaus Ohlmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Ohlmann), both glider pilots, the latter was the first pilot to glide over Everest. [Mountain waves](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Ejjmetz/mountainwaves.html) are air layers trying to stabilize after they are disturbed by relief:

[image: Mountain waves]

producing these beautiful [lenticular clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_cloud):

[image: Lenticular clouds over Les Druts]

<sup>Lenticular clouds over Alps, [source](https://www.seechamonix.com/weather)</sup>

**Stratospheric mountain waves**

Mountain waves are a strong lift source. Using stratospheric mountain waves, Airbus reached 23 km with two pilots onboard a [Windward Performance Perlan II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windward_Performance_Perlan_II), surpassing [U2 record](https://www.nj.com/entertainment/music/2009/09/u2_breaks_attendance_record_at.html)*:

[image: Airbus Perlan II mission]

<sup>Airbus Perlan II mission, [source](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/press-releases/en/2018/09/airbus-perlan-mission-ii-glider-soars-to-76-000-feet-to-break-ow.html)</sup>

**Absolute altitude versus height gain**

Flying at high altitude is not the biggest problem for a glider. You may start a bit below, gain a few altitude, and claim 6,000 m or 8,000 m. Any commercial airliner is able to glide from its cruise level, about 10-11 km. This is not soaring, that is using wind to gain altitude.

Gaining altitude requires specific skills, a good knowledge of winds, a favorable location and a great deal of cooperation from the weather. Not all gliders are equal, those made for high altitude may fly poorly at low altitude. There are glider categories to file a record at [FAI](https://www.fai.org/page/igc-about-us) because performances depend on the wingspan to extract lift.

- The record for gain of height is 12.9 km. It was set in 1961 and, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAI_Gliding_Commission#Open_class_records) never outdone in 60 years.
- In contrast altitude records were set over years, and Perlan II was able to fly at 23.2 km in 2018, but the glider was towed up to 12.2 km (40,000 ft) by a turboprop aircraft (tow release [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-tGMz-gxjI)) and from the [narrative](https://perlanproject.org/blog/perlan-2-soars-above-76000-feet) of the flight, there was no way (in this particular instance) to reach 12 km without being towed.

---

<sup>*Humor. U-2 record is [here](https://irp.fas.org/program/collect/n19981223_981999.html).</sup>

Comment: Just for clarification: 9140 m are 30,000 ft and 23 km are 75,500 ft.

Comment: This should be no problem at all. Even in the UK, where the highest mountain is about 4400 ft, the altitude record for a glider using ridge and wave lift is 32,000 ft.

Comment: Wow I thought there was only going to be a pithy answer of "yes, the space shuttle"

Comment: @llama while it may technically qualify as a glider on descent, highly polished bricks falling with style aren't really what most people have in mind when they think of gliders.  And in any event, the shuttle had essentially zero chance of ever gliding over the Himalayas; except for the remote possibility of an emergency landing the Shuttle always would reenter the atmosphere thousands of km farther East.

Comment: @llama A sailplane flies on thermal, ridge and wave lifts. The shuttle is no sailplane.

Comment: This answer is missing to mention the fact that any glider can fly at those heights. For decades the height record was at 15,000 metres (50,000ft) on a Grob G102 Std, a trainer glider. Way way higher than Everest. The big issue with flying at extreme heights is the need of more sophisticated oxygen equipment, the cold, and the coffin corner.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Not to mention the difficulty of eating, drinking and going to the lavatory in a comparatively cramped cockpit during the long period of time required for the ascent!

Comment: The most surprising fact is that it seems that you can glide over the Everest without being intercepted by Chinese fighters.

Comment: @Pere, perhaps [they glide over Nepal](https://www.adventurealternative.com/media/817345/8000m-peaks-flown-over-in-the-glider.jpeg?width=624px&height=216px), a sovereign state, rather than over Tibet, a Chinese region.

Comment: @mins - Yes, I might be understanding "over the Everest" (and over other border peaks mentioned in their web) in a too literal way.

Comment: @mins: yes, it's well known. He released at 12500ft.

Comment: @mins: and any normal glider can fly at those heights, if they somehow deal with the usual problems (cold and lack of oxygen). Which glider do you know that is not capable of flying that high, and why?

Comment: @mins: I don't know who wrote that in the Wikipedia article, but they have no idea what they are talking about. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY--mA-Iico) you have footage of a DG400 flying at 33,000ft, and there are higher flights. The height record before Harris' was by Paul Bikle, in a Schweizer 1-23E; any modern glider is insanely better than that. I have personally flown a Jantar Std at 27,500, and I have also personally seen many gliders flying higher than that. As for reaching the next wave, that has nothing to do with "ceiling", and all with pilot and weather.